# R: include an XML element not present in all records

Tags: r, xpath, error-handling, xml-parsing, dataframe

I am trying to develop a research timeline based on keyword data downloaded from PubMed. Thanks to many excellent examples, on this and other sites, I have come quite far. The attached code downloads an excel file based on the input query, then parses and converts it to an r-usable dataframe. The only problem is that the element, "KeywordList", refuses to cooperate. When commented out, everything runs as expected. However, when included, R produces the following error:

```
Error in FUN("pubmed_MedEng/MedEng01.xml"[[1L]], ...) : 
  object 'Keyword1' not found 
3 FUN("pubmed_MedEng/MedEng01.xml"[[1L]], ...) 
2 lapply(myxml.path, function(x) {
    myxml <- xmlParse(x, useInternalNodes = TRUE)
    padXML <- function(x, xstr) {
        res <- xpathSApply(x, xstr, xmlValue) ... 
1 pubmed_download("'medical English'", "MedEng")
```

I generated this and the other XPaths using a proper XML development tool, so I am fairly certain they are OK. I checked the XML file as well in the same fashion. Here's a relevant snippet:

```
  <?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE PubmedArticleSet PUBLIC "-//NLM//DTD PubMedArticle, 1st January 2015//EN" "http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/corehtml/query/DTD/pubmed_150101.dtd">
<PubmedArticleSet>
<PubmedArticle>
    <MedlineCitation Status="Publisher" Owner="NLM">
        <PMID Version="1">26269536</PMID>
        <DateCreated>
            <Year>2015</Year>
            <Month>8</Month>
            <Day>13</Day>
        </DateCreated>
        <DateRevised>
            <Year>2015</Year>
            <Month>8</Month>
            <Day>14</Day>
        </DateRevised>
        <Article PubModel="Print-Electronic">
            <Journal>
                <ISSN IssnType="Electronic">1527-974X</ISSN>
                <JournalIssue CitedMedium="Internet">
                    <PubDate>
                        <Year>2015</Year>
                        <Month>Aug</Month>
                        <Day>11</Day>
                    </PubDate>
                </JournalIssue>
                <Title>Journal of the American Medical Informatics Association : JAMIA</Title>
                <ISOAbbreviation>J Am Med Inform Assoc</ISOAbbreviation>
            </Journal>
            <ArticleTitle>Assessing the readability of clinicaltrials.gov.</ArticleTitle>
            <Pagination>
                <MedlinePgn/>
            </Pagination>
            <ELocationID EIdType="pii">ocv062</ELocationID>
            <ELocationID EIdType="doi">10.1093/jamia/ocv062</ELocationID>
            <Abstract>
                <AbstractText Label="OBJECTIVE" NlmCategory="OBJECTIVE">ClinicalTrials.gov serves critical functions of disseminating trial information to the public and helping the trials recruit participants. This study assessed the readability of trial descriptions at ClinicalTrials.gov using multiple quantitative measures.</AbstractText>
                <AbstractText Label="MATERIALS AND METHODS" NlmCategory="METHODS">The analysis included all 165 988 trials registered at ClinicalTrials.gov as of April 30, 2014. To obtain benchmarks, the authors also analyzed 2 other medical corpora: (1) all 955 Health Topics articles from MedlinePlus and (2) a random sample of 100 000 clinician notes retrieved from an electronic health records system intended for conveying internal communication among medical professionals. The authors characterized each of the corpora using 4 surface metrics, and then applied 5 different scoring algorithms to assess their readability. The authors hypothesized that clinician notes would be most difficult to read, followed by trial descriptions and MedlinePlus Health Topics articles.</AbstractText>
                <AbstractText Label="RESULTS" NlmCategory="RESULTS">Trial descriptions have the longest average sentence length (26.1 words) across all corpora; 65% of their words used are not covered by a basic medical English dictionary. In comparison, average sentence length of MedlinePlus Health Topics articles is 61% shorter, vocabulary size is 95% smaller, and dictionary coverage is 46% higher. All 5 scoring algorithms consistently rated CliniclTrials.gov trial descriptions the most difficult corpus to read, even harder than clinician notes. On average, it requires 18 years of education to properly understand these trial descriptions according to the results generated by the readability assessment algorithms.</AbstractText>
                <AbstractText Label="DISCUSSION AND CONCLUSION" NlmCategory="CONCLUSIONS">Trial descriptions at CliniclTrials.gov are extremely difficult to read. Significant work is warranted to improve their readability in order to achieve CliniclTrials.gov's goal of facilitating information dissemination and subject recruitment.</AbstractText>
                <CopyrightInformation>Published by Oxford University Press on behalf of the American Medical Informatics Association 2015. This work is written by US Government employees and is in the public domain in the US.</CopyrightInformation>
            </Abstract>
            <AuthorList>
                <Author>
                    <LastName>Wu</LastName>
                    <ForeName>Danny Ty</ForeName>
                    <Initials>DT</Initials>
                    <AffiliationInfo>
                        <Affiliation>School of Information, University of Michigan, Ann Arbor, MI, USA.</Affiliation>
                    </AffiliationInfo>
                </Author>
                <Author>
                    <LastName>Hanauer</LastName>
                    <ForeName>David A</ForeName>
                    <Initials>DA</Initials>
                    <AffiliationInfo>
                        <Affiliation>School of Information, University of Michigan, Ann Arbor, MI, USA Department of Pediatrics, University of Michigan, Ann Arbor, MI, USA.</Affiliation>
                    </AffiliationInfo>
                </Author>
                <Author>
                    <LastName>Mei</LastName>
                    <ForeName>Qiaozhu</ForeName>
                    <Initials>Q</Initials>
                    <AffiliationInfo>
                        <Affiliation>School of Information, University of Michigan, Ann Arbor, MI, USA Department of Electrical Engineering and Computer Science, University of Michigan, Ann Arbor, MI, USA.</Affiliation>
                    </AffiliationInfo>
                </Author>
                <Author>
                    <LastName>Clark</LastName>
                    <ForeName>Patricia M</ForeName>
                    <Initials>PM</Initials>
                    <AffiliationInfo>
                        <Affiliation>School of Nursing, University of Michigan, Ann Arbor, MI, USA Center for Health Communication Research, University of Michigan, Ann Arbor, MI, USA.</Affiliation>
                    </AffiliationInfo>
                </Author>
                <Author>
                    <LastName>An</LastName>
                    <ForeName>Lawrence C</ForeName>
                    <Initials>LC</Initials>
                    <AffiliationInfo>
                        <Affiliation>Center for Health Communication Research, University of Michigan, Ann Arbor, MI, USA Department of Internal Medicine, University of Michigan, Ann Arbor, MI, USA.</Affiliation>
                    </AffiliationInfo>
                </Author>
                <Author>
                    <LastName>Proulx</LastName>
                    <ForeName>Joshua</ForeName>
                    <Initials>J</Initials>
                    <AffiliationInfo>
                        <Affiliation>Department of Biomedical Informatics, University of Utah, Salt Lake City, UT, USA.</Affiliation>
                    </AffiliationInfo>
                </Author>
                <Author>
                    <LastName>Zeng</LastName>
                    <ForeName>Qing T</ForeName>
                    <Initials>QT</Initials>
                    <AffiliationInfo>
                        <Affiliation>Department of Biomedical Informatics, University of Utah, Salt Lake City, UT, USA.</Affiliation>
                    </AffiliationInfo>
                </Author>
                <Author>
                    <LastName>Vydiswaran</LastName>
                    <ForeName>Vg Vinod</ForeName>
                    <Initials>VV</Initials>
                    <AffiliationInfo>
                        <Affiliation>School of Information, University of Michigan, Ann Arbor, MI, USA.</Affiliation>
                    </AffiliationInfo>
                </Author>
                <Author>
                    <LastName>Collins-Thompson</LastName>
                    <ForeName>Kevyn</ForeName>
                    <Initials>K</Initials>
                    <AffiliationInfo>
                        <Affiliation>School of Information, University of Michigan, Ann Arbor, MI, USA Department of Electrical Engineering and Computer Science, University of Michigan, Ann Arbor, MI, USA.</Affiliation>
                    </AffiliationInfo>
                </Author>
                <Author>
                    <LastName>Zheng</LastName>
                    <ForeName>Kai</ForeName>
                    <Initials>K</Initials>
                    <AffiliationInfo>
                        <Affiliation>School of Information, University of Michigan, Ann Arbor, MI, USA School of Public Health Department of Health Management and Policy, University of Michigan, Ann Arbor, MI, USA kzheng@umich.edu.</Affiliation>
                    </AffiliationInfo>
                </Author>
            </AuthorList>
            <Language>ENG</Language>
            <PublicationTypeList>
                <PublicationType UI="">JOURNAL ARTICLE</PublicationType>
            </PublicationTypeList>
            <ArticleDate DateType="Electronic">
                <Year>2015</Year>
                <Month>8</Month>
                <Day>11</Day>
            </ArticleDate>
        </Article>
        <MedlineJournalInfo>
            <MedlineTA>J Am Med Inform Assoc</MedlineTA>
            <NlmUniqueID>9430800</NlmUniqueID>
            <ISSNLinking>1067-5027</ISSNLinking>
        </MedlineJournalInfo>
        <KeywordList Owner="NOTNLM">
            <Keyword MajorTopicYN="N">CliniclTrials.gov</Keyword>
            <Keyword MajorTopicYN="N">clinical trial</Keyword>
            <Keyword MajorTopicYN="N">comprehension</Keyword>
            <Keyword MajorTopicYN="N">electronic health records</Keyword>
            <Keyword MajorTopicYN="N">natural language processing</Keyword>
            <Keyword MajorTopicYN="N">readability</Keyword>
        </KeywordList>
    </MedlineCitation>
    <PubmedData>
        <History>
            <PubMedPubDate PubStatus="entrez">
                <Year>2015</Year>
                <Month>8</Month>
                <Day>14</Day>
                <Hour>6</Hour>
                <Minute>0</Minute>
            </PubMedPubDate>
            <PubMedPubDate PubStatus="pubmed">
                <Year>2015</Year>
                <Month>8</Month>
                <Day>14</Day>
                <Hour>6</Hour>
                <Minute>0</Minute>
            </PubMedPubDate>
            <PubMedPubDate PubStatus="medline">
                <Year>2015</Year>
                <Month>8</Month>
                <Day>14</Day>
                <Hour>6</Hour>
                <Minute>0</Minute>
            </PubMedPubDate>
        </History>
        <PublicationStatus>aheadofprint</PublicationStatus>
        <ArticleIdList>
            <ArticleId IdType="pii">ocv062</ArticleId>
            <ArticleId IdType="doi">10.1093/jamia/ocv062</ArticleId>
            <ArticleId IdType="pubmed">26269536</ArticleId>
        </ArticleIdList>
    </PubmedData>
</PubmedArticle>

<PubmedArticle>
    <MedlineCitation Owner="NLM" Status="MEDLINE">
        <PMID Version="1">5819388</PMID>
        <DateCreated>
            <Year>1969</Year>
            <Month>08</Month>
            <Day>22</Day>
        </DateCreated>
        <DateCompleted>
            <Year>1969</Year>
            <Month>08</Month>
            <Day>22</Day>
        </DateCompleted>
        <DateRevised>
            <Year>2007</Year>
            <Month>11</Month>
            <Day>15</Day>
        </DateRevised>
        <Article PubModel="Print">
            <Journal>
                <ISSN IssnType="Print">0026-1270</ISSN>
                <JournalIssue CitedMedium="Print">
                    <Volume>8</Volume>
                    <Issue>2</Issue>
                    <PubDate>
                        <Year>1969</Year>
                        <Month>Apr</Month>
                    </PubDate>
                </JournalIssue>
                <Title>Methods of information in medicine</Title>
                <ISOAbbreviation>Methods Inf Med</ISOAbbreviation>
            </Journal>
            <ArticleTitle>Identification and transformation of terminal morphemes in medical English.</ArticleTitle>
            <Pagination>
                <MedlinePgn>84-90</MedlinePgn>
            </Pagination>
            <AuthorList CompleteYN="Y">
                <Author ValidYN="Y">
                    <LastName>Pratt</LastName>
                    <ForeName>A W</ForeName>
                    <Initials>AW</Initials>
                </Author>
                <Author ValidYN="Y">
                    <LastName>Pacak</LastName>
                    <ForeName>M</ForeName>
                    <Initials>M</Initials>
                </Author>
            </AuthorList>
            <Language>eng</Language>
            <PublicationTypeList>
                <PublicationType UI="D016428">Journal Article</PublicationType>
            </PublicationTypeList>
        </Article>
        <MedlineJournalInfo>
            <Country>GERMANY, WEST</Country>
            <MedlineTA>Methods Inf Med</MedlineTA>
            <NlmUniqueID>0210453</NlmUniqueID>
            <ISSNLinking>0026-1270</ISSNLinking>
        </MedlineJournalInfo>
        <CitationSubset>IM</CitationSubset>
        <MeshHeadingList>
            <MeshHeading>
                <DescriptorName MajorTopicYN="Y" UI="D000043">Abstracting and Indexing as Topic</DescriptorName>
            </MeshHeading>
            <MeshHeading>
                <DescriptorName MajorTopicYN="Y" UI="D003201">Computers</DescriptorName>
            </MeshHeading>
            <MeshHeading>
                <DescriptorName MajorTopicYN="Y" UI="D008037">Linguistics</DescriptorName>
            </MeshHeading>
            <MeshHeading>
                <DescriptorName MajorTopicYN="N" UI="D009316">National Institutes of Health (U.S.)</DescriptorName>
            </MeshHeading>
            <MeshHeading>
                <DescriptorName MajorTopicYN="N" Type="Geographic" UI="D014481">United States</DescriptorName>
            </MeshHeading>
        </MeshHeadingList>
    </MedlineCitation>
    <PubmedData>
        <History>
            <PubMedPubDate PubStatus="pubmed">
                <Year>1969</Year>
                <Month>4</Month>
                <Day>1</Day>
            </PubMedPubDate>
            <PubMedPubDate PubStatus="medline">
                <Year>1969</Year>
                <Month>4</Month>
                <Day>1</Day>
                <Hour>0</Hour>
                <Minute>1</Minute>
            </PubMedPubDate>
            <PubMedPubDate PubStatus="entrez">
                <Year>1969</Year>
                <Month>4</Month>
                <Day>1</Day>
                <Hour>0</Hour>
                <Minute>0</Minute>
            </PubMedPubDate>
        </History>
        <PublicationStatus>ppublish</PublicationStatus>
        <ArticleIdList>
            <ArticleId IdType="pubmed">5819388</ArticleId>
            <ArticleId IdType="pii">69020084</ArticleId>
        </ArticleIdList>
    </PubmedData>
</PubmedArticle>

</PubmedArticleSet>
```

Here is the offending portion code (only). Please forgive me if this excerpt has a minor syntax error or 2. Thanks in advance for any/all advice. I hope a solution here will be useful to anyone else bullied into grinding through PubMed for JBosses.

```
  ##########################  
  # PUBMED XML TO DATAFRAME
  ########################

  library(XML)
  library(reshape)

  # initializes save path to XML files
  dir <- paste0("pubmed_",input.dir)
  myxml.path = file.path(dir, dir(dir, ".xml"))


  ## function to process xml files in the given save path
  pub.data <- lapply(myxml.path, function(x){


    myxml <- xmlParse(x, useInternalNodes = TRUE)

    ## function(s) to pad XML columns with ""
    padXML <-function(x,xstr){
      res<-xpathSApply(x,xstr,xmlValue)
      if(length(res)==0){
        out<-""
      }else{
        out<-res
      }
      out
    }

#    padXML <-function(x, xstr){
#     res <- xpathSApply(x, xstr, xmlValue)
#      ifelse(try(length(res)==0, silent=TRUE), "NA", 
#            ifelse(length(res)==0, "", 
#                   ifelse(length(res)>1, paste(res, collapse=", "), res)))
#    }


#    padXML <-function(x, xstr){
#      res <- tryCatch(xpathSApply(x, xstr, xmlValue), error=function(e) print(""))
#      return(res)
#    }



    ## Extract XML paths
    PMID <- xpathSApply(myxml,"//*/MedlineCitation",padXML,xstr='./PMID/text()')
    ArticleTitle <- xpathSApply(myxml,"//*/MedlineCitation",padXML,xstr='./Article[1]/ArticleTitle[1]/text()')
    DateCreated <- xpathSApply(myxml,"//*/MedlineCitation",padXML,xstr='./DateCreated/Year/text()')
    Keyword1 < - xpathSApply(myxml,"//*/MedlineCitation",padXML,xstr='./KeywordList[1]/Keyword[1]/text()')
    Keyword2 < - xpathSApply(myxml,"//*/MedlineCitation",padXML,xstr='./KeywordList[1]/Keyword[2]/text()')
    Keyword3 < - xpathSApply(myxml,"//*/MedlineCitation",padXML,xstr='./KeywordList[1]/Keyword[3]/text()')

    ## builds dataframe from extracted XML paths
    pub.data <- data.frame(
      PMID,
      DateCreated,
      ArticleTitle,
      Keyword1,
      Keyword2,
      Keyword3,
      stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

  })

  pub.data <- merge_all(pub.data)
  return(pub.data)
```

References:

1. [Creating a dataset from an XML file in R statistics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11654711/creating-a-dataset-from-an-xml-file-in-r-statistics)
2. [R-XML pulling nodes into matrix/DF accounting for missing nodes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31999486/r-xml-pulling-nodes-into-matrix-df-accounting-for-missing-nodes)
3. [XPath fails on an XML document in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30984420/xpath-fails-on-an-xml-document-in-r)
4. [catching an error and then branching logic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2158780/r-catching-an-error-and-then-branching-logic?rq=1)
5. http://rpsychologist.com/how-to-download-complete-xml-records-from-pubmed-and-extract-data

Comment: You obviously put a lot of effort into writing this question. Can you reduce it to the essence of the problem? For instance, can you identify an instance of `myxml` that reproduces the problem, and post that, rather than all this code.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. I edited my post per your comment. The code is now shorter, but I had to add in the generated XML as a result. I hope this arrangement, however, is more manageable. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This might be trivial. You have a space between `<` and `-` (as in `< -` rather than `<-`), in just those three assignments. When I fix that it runs.

Comment: @jlhoward   Wow. Thank you so very much. It amazing, the difference between the experienced programmer and the neophyte, when it comes to spotting things like that. I hope, at least, this post will be useful for others.

Comment: Not so amazing actually. I spent a lot of time messing with the xPath before stumbling on that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Too long for a comment. [If people think this is too trivial to be an answer (I'm inclined to think it might be...), I'll delete it.]

So the problem was a typo (see the comments). This is just a note on programming practice. Lining up assignment statements (as much as possible), so this:

```
ArticleTitle <- xpathSApply(myxml,"//*/MedlineCitation",padXML,xstr='./Article[1]/ArticleTitle[1]/text()')
DateCreated  <- xpathSApply(myxml,"//*/MedlineCitation",padXML,xstr='./DateCreated/Year/text()')
Keyword1     < - xpathSApply(myxml,"//*/MedlineCitation",padXML,xstr='./KeywordList[1]/Keyword[1]/text()')
Keyword2     < - xpathSApply(myxml,"//*/MedlineCitation",padXML,xstr='./KeywordList[1]/Keyword[2]/text()')
Keyword3     < - xpathSApply(myxml,"//*/MedlineCitation",padXML,xstr='./KeywordList[1]/Keyword[3]/text()')
```

instead of this:

```
ArticleTitle <- xpathSApply(myxml,"//*/MedlineCitation",padXML,xstr='./Article[1]/ArticleTitle[1]/text()')
DateCreated <- xpathSApply(myxml,"//*/MedlineCitation",padXML,xstr='./DateCreated/Year/text()')
Keyword1 < - xpathSApply(myxml,"//*/MedlineCitation",padXML,xstr='./KeywordList[1]/Keyword[1]/text()')
Keyword2 < - xpathSApply(myxml,"//*/MedlineCitation",padXML,xstr='./KeywordList[1]/Keyword[2]/text()')
Keyword3 < - xpathSApply(myxml,"//*/MedlineCitation",padXML,xstr='./KeywordList[1]/Keyword[3]/text()')
```

makes errors of this type really pop.